# Does one of the US Income Tax free file services allow for no-fee 1099 entry?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099, software, form-1099-misc

I've started to file my income tax with the HR Block free file service, but I'm getting hit with a 30 dollar upgrade prompt when I go to put in my 1099s. I have one capital gains 1099-MISC, one savings account 1099-INT, and one 1099-MISC from working as an Amazon delivery contractor. Is there a different free file provider that doesn't charge for 1099 entry? I'd prefer not to guess and test a bunch. And if not, is it too late to mail a 1040 as of 4/13/18? Thanks.

Comment: FreeTaxUSA.com seems to do self-employed as part of its "free" option, and charges a reasonable fee for state, but no first-hand experience with that one. I use TaxSlayer, all forms included in the $24 "Classic" option, state is still extra.  Some states have an easy and free e-file of their own, and they're usually based on figures from your federal return so pretty easy to do separately and save a little money.

Comment: You could check Credit Karma.

Comment: I have used FreeTaxUSA for the past several years and been happy with it.  It handles self-employment earnings, capital gains, the works, for no charge on the federal return.  (You do have to pay for the state return, but the fee is small.)

Comment: Keep in mind if you're sure you are getting a refund the April 15th (17th this year) date is not a requirement.  You have up to 3 years to file.

Answer (score 3):

The IRS Free Fillable Forms does, or at least I entered info from several 1099s in mine.

Comment: That's what I used when I did my own taxes. Not the most convenient UI but free and straightforward.

Comment: I second or third Free Fillable Forms. After a couple years you get the hang of it. Although it may not be a good option if you are in  a rush.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know for sure whether or not there are any free tax software apps that handle your situation, but when you did the job that got you the 1099-MISC you were technically self-employed. This complicates your return and is an advanced feature that is not generally available in the free versions of tax software.

To answer your second question, the tax due date this year is Tuesday, April 17, 2018. Your mailed return needs to be postmarked by that date. Post Offices used to stay open on tax day until midnight to accommodate late filers. I don’t think they all do that anymore, but [some are still open late that day](https://www.usps.com/taxes/), and as long as you get your tax return to your local post office before it closes that day, you should be fine.